# Resources to Learn to Code for Math Research.

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, online-resources

I was told that coding is a very good skill to have in order to conduct math research (and a good skill to have in general, of course). (I also know that many people in the MathOverflow community hold this viewpoint, for instance Steve Huntsman.)

Nowadays, there are many good online resources for learning the coding skills. However, there seems to be very few resources with emphasis on using coding for answering mathematical questions.

**My Question**: are there resources (books, courses, etc.) with emphasis on using coding for answering mathematical questions?

Here, I am thinking of something in a similar vein as Project Euler but with harder mathematics.

I prefer to use one of the following languages since they seem to be the best general-purpose tools:

- Python/Sage
- Mathematica

Maple is also acceptable.

Just to make my question more specific: my goal is to be able to work computationally for all undergraduate (group/ring/Galois theory, single/multivarib calculus, linear algebra, ODEs, complex analysis, combinatorics, elem number theory, etc.) and standard graduate topics (functional analysis, representation theory, algebraic geometry, algebraic/differential topology, Riemannian geometry, etc) whenever possible.

Comment: Not sure if this qualifies, but there have been several subject-specific books written that involve heavy use of certain computer algebra systems. For example, [**Exploring Abstract Algebra with Mathematica**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387986197) by Hibbard/Levasseur, [**Complex Analysis with Mathematica**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0521836263) by Shaw, [**Modern Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces with Mathematica**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1584884487) by Abbena/Salamon/Gray, [**Advanced Mathematical Methods with Maple**](https://www.amazon.com//dp/0521779812) by Richards, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at published mathematics and computer science articles. For example, a free online resource that features math and computer science papers is [Math and CS Research](https://mathcsr.org). It explores the ways coding can be applied both theoretically and to the real world.